# Can't reload eslint configuration file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm working on a React application (created via Create React App) and I'm extending the linting configuration.

In my `src` folder I have the file `.eslintrc.js` which is the following:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['react-app'],
  rules: {
    'max-len': ['error', { code: 80 }],
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['**/*.ts?(x)'],
      rules: {
        'additional-typescript-only-rule': 'warn',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Since it prevents the app from compiling I changed the `'error'` to a `'warning'` so that it throws just a warning but the application still works.
The problem is that if I run the command `npx eslint ./src` I can see that it throws just warnings, but when I execute `npm run start` it stucks to the old version of the file:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/ProfitLineChart/index.jsx
  Line 101:1:  This line has a length of 87. Maximum allowed is 80  max-len
```

How can I fix this? I have already tried to restart the terminal and it doesn't work

Comment: the answer is already present in message. you have set max-len rule in eslint.

Comment: Yes, but I changed from error to warning and it still gives error. Even if I change from 80 to 300 running `npm start` always complain about the length of 80 while when I run `npx eslint ./src` it gives the correct output. The only way I found so far to update the rules is to remove the `./node modules` folder and run `npm i` again...